# Bootstrap Modal doesnt work well

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to open a form with bootstrap modal, my first problem was that bootstrap modal disappear immediately after click on my button but searching in other questions I found the solution deleting from my template:

> {!!Html::script('js/plugins/bootstrap.min.js')!!}

Now I have other problem, the form of modal open but I can not do nothing, I can not submit my form, I attached a file with photo. 
[image]

It's all dark and I can not do nothing.

- How can I fix this problem?
- Is a problem if I deleted bootstrap.min.js ?(I'm afraid that after something goes wrong)
- There other way to create modal form? (maybe javascript)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: can you please put SO snippet or fiddle of it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modal is may be inside some other div , that is affecting it . Try putting it outside that div it will work !! Or try putting this in your css file it may work `div.modal div.modal-backdrop {
    z-index: 0;
}`